# How to copy iPhone contacts on Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, iphone, contacts, transfer

I just got a new Mac. My iPhone contacts are extensive and complete. I understand that if I want to sync the computer and the IPhone, I must make sure the computer is the source since all existing info on the iPhone will be overwritten.
I don't know what to do.Who can help me?
Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 6):

Sync is two-way. Be sure to backup your iPhone first in case something goes wrong though.

---

Alternatively, use [iPhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

> Full Contact List Access
>   Need to grab contacts from an iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch? PhoneView displays your entire contact list organized by contact group. Simply drag contacts to the Desktop to save V-card files or send contacts directly to your Mac OS X Address Book.

---

Alternatively, migrate your contacts from your previous computer, if they're on there. If it's a Mac, you can use Migration Assistant, and if it's not, you can usually export to vCards.